# What to use instead of null

Tags: c#

```
static int min(int[] arr, int a)
    {
        int min = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < a; i++)
            if (arr[i] < min)
                min = arr[i];
        return min;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        int i;
        Console.WriteLine("Vnesi števila: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int stevilo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (stevilo == 0)
                break;
            arr[i] = stevilo;
        }

        if (i < 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Napaka - premalo števil!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        int min1 = min(arr, i);

        int? min2 = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            int stevilo = arr[j];
            if(stevilo != min1 && (min2 == null || stevilo < min2))
                min2 = stevilo;
        }

        if(min2 == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Napaka - vsa števila enaka!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Drugo najmanjše: " + min2.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}
So this code reads from 2 to 10 numbers and writes out the second smallest out of one of them. You can cancel entering the numbers with the key 0. In a case where the second smallest number can't be written out(all entered are for instance 5 5 5 5), then no number is written out).

BUT I found out that we can't use null values, so what can I replace it with? Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use `null`?  What's preventing that?

Comment: school doesn't allow it

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with null?

Comment: well read the code I kinda forgot it because I wrote it like 1 month ago, I just know that it works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the min2 variable to 0 then test it when you need to search for the min value and do not use a nullable integer

```
    int min2 = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        int stevilo = arr[j];
        if(stevilo != 0 && stevilo != min1 && stevilo < min2))
            min2 = stevilo;
    }

    if(min2 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Napaka - vsa števila enaka!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Drugo najmanjše: " + min2.ToString());
```

You should also change the input loop to avoid problems with the user input

```
int stevilo;
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if(!Int32.TryParse(userInput, out stevilo) || stevilo == 0)
    break;
arr[i] = stevilo;
```

The use of Int32.TryParse avoids an exception if your user types something that cannot be converted to an integer number

Comment: can't use any of that either

Comment: Yes, the elements of the array are automatically initialized with zero, so this could also use as a signpost when you need to stop, updating

Answer (score 0):

Well, a strange constraint, but once you have it, then just use a `bool` flag or  the fact that the `min2` must be different from `min1` like this

```
// ...

int min1 = min(arr, i);

int min2 = min1;
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    int stevilo = arr[j];
    if(stevilo != min1 && (min2 == min1 || stevilo < min2))
        min2 = stevilo;
}

if(min2 != min1)
    Console.WriteLine("Napaka - vsa števila enaka!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Drugo najmanjše: " + min2.ToString());
```